# Assigning values in the predicate of a while loop - BufferedReader

Tags: java, while-loop, variable-assignment, bufferedreader

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
public void cinemaFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.equals("Movies")) {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null 
                    && !line.equals("Theaters")) {

                String currentline = line; 
                String[] parts = currentline.split(":");
                String part1 = parts[0]; 
                String part2 = parts[1]; 
                movies.add(new Movie(part1, part2));
            }
        }

    reader.close();
}
```

As you can see, I assign line a value in the termination clause of the while loop.

I am new to BufferedReaders and I am looking for an alternative to this. IE, I want to have the assignment statement("line = reader.readLine()") in a separate statement, external to the while loop termination clause.

I have tried moving "line = reader.readLine()" into the body of the while loop but that doesn't work. I have also tried putting it right before the while loop, which also doesn't work.

I think I have fundamentally misunderstood how BufferedReaders work, can they only iterate through the lines in while loops?

Comment: Can you give an example of your input file and a description of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull the assignment out of the `while` loop condition, you must understand that the `while` loop condition is evaluated once before the first iteration, and after the end of each iteration.

You can emulate that by placing the assignment before the `while` loop even begins, and also adding it to the end of the `while` loop body.

```
line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // Rest of body is untouched

    // Read again at the end.
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

This will operate the same.  It may even be a little clearer than having the assignment in the condition of the `while` loop, even if it's a little less concise.

The `BufferedReader` does nothing special in this regard with `while` loops.  It just returns `null` when `readLine()` is called and there's no input left.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String line;
while (true) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    if(line == null)
        break;

    if (line.equals("Movies")) {
```